# Flutter need client server Tcp

Tags: flutter, sockets, server, tcp, serversocket

A server that will keep a permanent connection via Tcp. And close when the program is shut down.

An example of connecting a server that reconnects every time:

```
class Server {
  void connectToServer() async {
    try {
      Socket _socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 7890);
      log('connected: ${_socket.address}:${_socket.port}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  void send(temp) async {
    Socket _socket = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 7890);
    _socket.listen((List<int> event) {
      log(utf8.decode(event));
    });
    _socket.add(utf8.encode(temp));
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot detect any real question here, i.e. it is unclear to me what the problem is you need help with.

Comment: It is necessary to make sure that the server does not constantly reconnect, but connects once and throughout the entire time data is sent through this connection and not a new one is created